# Beowulf Cluster - Identical users on slave nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc

In relation to building a Beowulf cluster, why is it necessary to create identical users on the slave nodes? If one were to create the users on the slave nodes in a different order to the order in which they were created on the master node, what problems would occur and how would one fix them?

I have been trying to find a concrete answer to this for a few hours but with no luck. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of SSH access/file permissions.

If one computer needs to access other it must have some sort of remote login technology, and SSH uses user names. Also if you have a file share between them, you may run into problems with file permissions when one pc writes them as one user and other tries to read them as other.

Regarding user creation, by default if you don't specify a user id your user gets the next available. In Ubuntu case, normal accounts start with UID 1000 so if you create 3 users you will get the following

```
USER NAME    ID
user1        1000
user2        1001
user3        1002
```

If in a different machine you change the order, the users will have different user ids. Of course, you can avoid that providing the desired UID when you create the accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because they most likely share some sort of file system such as /home. Any shared software will need certain permissions and the permissions will correspond to a uid or groupid. If there is a user "user" on one machine with a different uid than "user" on another machine, some of the shared filesystem won't be accessible.

To fix it you would need to add the user on each machine with the specific matching uid.

Answer (score 0):

When a MPI program is running in several nodes is necessary to login this nodes, write files etc. If the users is no sync between headnode and nodes you can't even to find the executable because the users permission in NFS share.